# Can not authorize in unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have page with `login_required` decorator which I want to test whether correct template is used. On stackoverflow I've found authorization method for unit test but for me it do not work for some reason. Here is my test:

```
 from django.test import TestCase
 from django.test import Client
 import base64


class TestUsingCorrectTemplates(TestCase):

 def test_correct_classroom_template_used(self):
    auth_headers = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic '+base64.b64encode('admin@dot.com:admin')}
    c = Client()
    response = c.get('/classroom/', **auth_headers)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response,'classroom.html')
```

Also would like to mention that authorization handled with OpenId/AllAuth and there is no `/login` page, user logs in from start page `/`

Content of `response` variable is following:

```
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://testserver/?next=/classroom/
```

Test error:

```
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind that when running tests, you don't have any users to authenticate against. You would need to add them to the database first. You may also need to use Mock to mock out your request and access tokens.

Comment: And if you're using `login_required`, faking HTTP authorization in your test won't help in any way at all.

Comment: so how can I make my tests passing?

Comment: The 302 means you're getting a redirect, not necessarily a disaster -- what happens if you **follow** the redirect...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP code 302 means that your server is sending a redirect response. You should tell your client to follow redirects so that you deal with the actual login page. You can change your `get` call like this:

```
response = c.get('/classroom/', follow=True, **auth_headers)
```

If you want to check the intermediate redirection steps you can inspect `response.redirect_chain`. It is all documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a user and [calling the `login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) method of your `Client` instance?

```python
import base64

from django.test import TestCase


class TestUsingCorrectTemplates(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create your user here
        # self.user = ...

    def test_correct_classroom_template_used(self):
        self.client.login('admin@dot.com', 'admin')
        response = self.client.get('/classroom/')  # XXX: You should use url reversal here.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'classroom.html')
```